Filter data using multiple sets of checkboxes to determine the criteria
I am trying filter data using multiple sets of checkboxes to determine the criteria.
Here is the spreadsheet I am working on. Here are some notes about each sheet:

Dashboard: I have four sets of criteria I am looking to use to filter using checkboxes, including a date range
List: Where the formula populates (Cell A2)
History: The data set I am attempting to filter. I have hidden rows I am not using as Criteria.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
I am currently trying the xmatch function, which works with one set of checkboxes (Below is the formula I have tried). However, attempting to apply a second xmath function using a separate set of checkbox ranges, everything gets wonky and counts things It should not.
=sort(filter(History!A:Z,History!B:B >= Dashboard!C4,  History!B:B <= Dashboard!C5,  xmatch(History!T:T,filter(Dashboard!O8:O57,Dashboard!N8:N57) )),2, true)
Here is the formula I attempted to try with multiple
=sort(filter(History!A:Z,History!B:B >= Dashboard!C4,  History!B:B <= Dashboard!C5,  xmatch(History!A:A,filter(Dashboard!F4:F5,Dashboard!E4:E5), xmatch(History!Z:Z,filter(Dashboard!I4:I6,Dashboard!H4:H6) )),2, true)

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Add a Filter Button
Upon seeing the setup of your sample file, I would like to suggest adding another button for the filter feature since I realized it will take some time in checking/un-checking the checkboxes and filling up the end date and start date (which makes simple triggers less efficient for this case). You may use the following script for this:
function filter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shFilter = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var startDate = shFilter.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var endDate = shFilter.getRange("C5").getValue();
  var selectVersion = shFilter.getRange("E4:F5").getValues().filter(x => x[0]).map(y => y[1]); // Change range if selection expands
  var selectNetwork = shFilter.getRange("H4:I6").getValues().filter(x => x[0]).map(y => y[1]); // Change range if selection expands
  var selectAudience = shFilter.getRange("K4:L10").getValues().filter(x => x[0]).map(y => y[1]); // Change range if selection expands
  var selectStates = shFilter.getRange("N8:O57").getValues().filter(x => x[0]).map(y => y[1]); // Change range if selection expands
  var rawData = ss.getSheetByName("History").getDataRange().getValues();
  var out = rawData.filter(a => (a[1] >= startDate) * (a[1] <= endDate) * (selectVersion.includes(a[0])) * (selectNetwork.includes(a[25])) * (selectAudience.includes(a[22])) * (selectStates.includes(a[19]))); //filtered raw data
  var shOut = ss.getSheetByName("List");
  shOut.getRange(2, 1, shOut.getLastRow() - 1, shOut.getLastColumn()).clearContent(); //clears previous data
  ss.getSheetByName("List").getRange(2, 1, out.length, out[0].length).setValues(out); //places the new filtered data
}

NOTE: I would have loved to show the output in this post but I think that the sample data you provided contains sensitive information.
References

filter


Feel free to ask anything with respect to the answer posted above.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I did plan to share a markdown table for the output but the data is sensitive in my opinion.
